# How to properly work with a scope which might have been destroyed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-scope, lifecycle

I have a lot of code like this:

```
app.directive(... function(...) { return function($scope...) {
    // add utilties like safeApply, handleError etc.
    decorateScope($scope);

    /**
     * Starts some-XXXX request that will run in the background for a while
     */
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
        someService.doSomethingThatTakesAWhile(...)
        .then(function(result) {
            // success!
            $scope...                               // DANGER!
        })
        .finally(function(result) {
            $scope.$apply();                        // DANGER!
        })
        .catch($scope.handleError.bind($scope));    // DANGER!
    };
};});
```

The three lines marked with `DANGER!` bear an awful fallacy: By the time the service has completed the requested action, `$scope` might have been destroyed (e.g. because it was part of a page that is not active anymore; my page system uses `ng-if`, etc.), and operating on a destroyed `$scope` is certainly not a good idea.

Is there an Angular way out of this mess?

Comment: wow, there are a couple things that jump out at me.  First, I would probably find a way to use `$q` to defer those long running tasks.  Beyond that, this is an ideal use case for isolated scopes in a directive.

Comment: @AndrewCounts They are already using promises. Agreed though, the problem here is that you're directly modifying someone else's scope - something which is shifting responsibility. Either move that call out to a service, or try and move the logic to an isolated scope - that way the person who owns the `$scope` can really be in charge of what happens when it's gone.

Comment: @RGraham Who is the person that owns the scope? This is inside a directive's `link` function. It can't get much closer to the scope than that? You are saying, I should add `$scope.$on('destroy',...` to set `$scope = null;` inside the `link` function, and add a null-check before every use? Or are you saying that moving this code somewhere else will somehow remedy that?

Comment: I didn't realise the `$scope` was that of the directive. You could reject the promise on destroy of the scope: `$scope.$on("destroy", doSomethingThatTakesAWhile.reject("Destroyed"));` and handle that reject in a special way. `if(result !== "Destroyed") { $scope.doStuff(); }`

Comment: @RGraham That seems much more complex than plainly nulling the `$scope` on destroy? I reckon that `ng-if` is a rather late addition to Angular... Maybe they will come up with better strategies in the near future, or maybe it will just fall under the table when Angular 2.0 comes :P

Comment: @AndrewCounts Would you mind explaining how isolated-ness can fix this issue? Also note that `defer` is not part of [the A+ standard](https://promisesaplus.com/) and [being deprecated](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#deferred-migration) all over the place, for a good reason.

Comment: Just because the scope is destroyed doesn't mean that the scope object is undefined. It just means that this scope will not participate in the digest cycle and it gets detached from the parent. So, I don't see any danger here

Comment: @NewDev Calling `$apply` on it, for example, fails - Doesn't it? Gotta check that again...

Comment: @Domi, with an exception? No, right? It just doesn't do anything, because it is "destroyed", but what is the danger?

Comment: @NewDev Ah now I remember... I am doing [safeApply](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js) which checks `$scope.$root` which is nulled out... So maybe there is no big issue after all?

Comment: Actually, I think `.$root` would be null for a destroyed scope, so it's not "safeApply" after all. At any rate, functions defined on the destroyed scope will still execute, but things like `$apply` would not work (but also not throw)

Comment: @NewDev Yeah sounds great. Silent ignore treatment :) I fixed my issues for now by simply adding an `if (!$scope.$root) return;`. Gonna adjust my treatment of scopes in accordance with this revelation (luckily not much adjustment needed)!